iisnode encountered an error when processing the request. with HTTP subStatus: 1001
I am a beginner. I have created a WebRTC application using React, along with Socket.IO and Peer. Currently, I am facing a problem when testing it on the server, and I encountered this error. What is it? I don't understand at all.
iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1001
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error


My website is divided into a frontend, which is the webpage, and a backend that serves as an API for the webpage to fetch data. Can someone please help me? Could you provide guidance on what I should study further and what might be causing the problem? Thank you very much.
I tried to change the web.config file and modified most of the code, but to be honest, I don’t really understand much at all.

First, think twice before continuing with iisnode, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-rough-history-of-iis-httpplatformhandler/

what is your frontend and backend project? and have you deployed both on iis? make sure you have installed iisnode module. what is your web.config file?
